# Jquery slider with different range steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to create a jQuery UI slider. This slider will have a limit of 300 and multiple range steps to go to that number (ex : 0 to 20 with value "5" steps / 20 to 50 with value "10" steps, etc.) as you can see on the picture in the link below.

[image: Multiple range steps in my slider]

As far as i understand, i can only put one step value to increment my slider.

I've seen this example : http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/ui-slider/slider_test.html but i don't really know how to implement it.

Someone can help me to figure a solution ?

Comment: How does the example you point to relate to your question? The steps there seem uniform.

Comment: Well, forget this link, it is not that relevant in my case.

Comment: Can you provide code of previous attempts?